# C# Panel.Refresh() not calling paint method

Tags: c#, panel, repaint, .refresh

I am trying to call **panel1** paint method to repaint the panel with a orange line (it is initiated with a blue line).

I have tried invalidate(), update() and refresh(), but nothing seems to call the paint event of panel1...

The paint event handler have been added to the panel1:

```
this.panel1.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.panel1_Paint);
```

Can someone please assist?

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        Form1 testForm = new Form1();
        Application.Run(testForm);

        testForm.drawNewLine();
    }
}
```

---

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool blueLine = true;
    bool orangeLine = false;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;

        if (blueLine == true)
        {
            Pen bluePen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 3);
            g.DrawLine(bluePen, 30, 50, 30, 250);
        }
        else if (orangeLine == true)
        {
            Pen orangePen = new Pen(Color.Orange, 3);
            g.DrawLine(orangePen, 30, 50, 30, 250);
        }

        g.Dispose();
    }

    public void drawNewLine()
    {
        blueLine = false;
        orangeLine = true;
        //panel1.Invalidate();
        //panel1.Update();
        panel1.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Application.Run(testForm);` blocks until form is closed, so when `drawNewLine()` is called - form does not exist anymore (create a button which calls it on click and check yourself, the code is working). `Invalidate()` should work just fine.

Also, you should not dispose `Graphics` object which is passed to your code in paint event. You were not responsible for creating it, so let the code which created it to destroy it.

Also, dispose `Pen` objects since you are creating them.